# Specify ListUrl for Event receiver

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, event-receivers

I need to add an event receiver on a list in substite.
My list is: *test*
in subsite: */sites/mysite2*

I tried a lot of combination but always same result when i try to deploy:

> The list doesn't exist

If I browse this in IE it works: */sites/mysite2/Lists/test*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deploy your feature to **Web Scope** and enable the feature on your *subsite*.

[image: Feature Scope]

Register the event receiver (*element.xml*) with:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/test">
```